# How to show list authors with at least five posts published

Tags: author, list-authors

i'm wondering if there is a way to use wp_list_authors to list only the authors with at least five (or even more, but anyway more than just one or two) published post in the blog.

Actually I don't see any "arg" to do that.

Thanks
Bye

Carletto

Answer (score 1):

Hacky way of doing it:

```
global $wpdb;
$min_posts = 5; // Make sure it's int, it's not escaped in the query
$author_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT `post_author` FROM
    (SELECT `post_author`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM {$wpdb->posts}
        WHERE `post_status`='publish' GROUP BY `post_author`) AS `stats`
    WHERE `count` >= {$min_posts} ORDER BY `count` DESC;");
// Do what you want to $author_ids from here on...
```

This will return the **User IDs** of the Authors with *5+ published posts* and orders them descending, by post counts. Don't think **wp_list_authors** supports what you need but you can always roll your own :)